# Is there a comparable R method to Panda's to_datetime? Char to POSIXct issue

Tags: r

I'm simply attempting to take a string (char) time (mm:ss.s) (minute:second.fractional second) to a POSIXct object.

I've attempted many solutions with base R and lubridate, but I can't seem to preserve the fractional second.

In Python, I can simply use to_datetime and I can parse out what I need into the correct object type.

I'm wondering from the community if there is a solution.

The column data looks like this if you need a more clear visual:

`> glimpse(update_times$Times)
 chr [1:318] "24:45.0" "24:11.8" "22:22.6"`

Thank you in advance. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lubridate::ms(c("24:45.0", "24:11.8", "22:22.6"))
## [1] "24M 45S"   "24M 11.8S" "22M 22.6S"
```

Comment: Thank you @Ista , but I'm confused how to go from this output.  `> glimpse(update_times$Times)
Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  ..@ .Data : num [1:318] 45 11.8 22.6 19.1 6.9 0.7 47.9 28 52.9 19.8 ...
  ..@ year  : num [1:318] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ month : num [1:318] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ day   : num [1:318] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ hour  : num [1:318] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ minute: num [1:318] 24 24 22 21 23 26 21 24 22 23 ...` to a POSIXct object. Thanks.

Comment: @Evans You can't. From `?POSIXct`: "Class ‘"POSIXct"’
     represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of
     1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector". Unless you also have date and hour information `POSIXct` won't work.

Comment: @Insta First off thank you. If I only have the time (e.g. 1 mile run, time to completion for baking a pizza), I think I'm needing to treat as a duration object (from lubridate), not a time based object? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible with the standard `strptime()` function. From `help(strptime)`:

```
## time with fractional seconds
z <- strptime("20/2/06 11:16:16.683", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")
z # prints without fractional seconds
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
z
options(op)
```